# PHP grouping by data value

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

My data variable:

```
1=icon_arrow.gif,2=icon_arrow.gif,3=icon_arrow.gif
```

I need it to be grouped by the value after =, so in this case it should look like this:

```
$out = array('icon_arrow.gif' => '1, 2, 3');
```

The 'icon_arrow.gif' field need to be unique, and can't repeat.

How it can be done?

Comment: whats the source of the original string?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I completely do not understand the question. ha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun. With no special chars this should also work.

```
$str="1=icon_arrow.gif,2=icon_arrow.gif,3=icon_arrow.gif,4=x.gif";

$str = str_replace(',', '&', $str);
parse_str($str, $array);
$result = array();
foreach($array as $k=>$v)
    $result[$v] = (isset($result[$v]) ? $result[$v] . ", " : "") . $k;
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialize an array:

```
$array = array();
```

Explode the input by `,`, store results as an array based on a sub-explode of it by `=`:

```
foreach(explode(',', $string) as $p)
{
   list($i, $n) = explode('=',$p);
   $array[$n][] = $i;
}
```

Implode then the result with `,`:

```
foreach($array as &$v)
    $v = implode(', ', $v);
unset($v);
```

Done.

Comment: Well geez. You did the whole thing for him. How will he ever learn? ;)

Comment: Well SO is a browser game: If you hinder users from learning from their questions, they will ask more question, you can easily answer and then you get the points ;)

Comment: I've learned everything already :p , because I understand the whole code, I just was having some troubles with the interpretation.